# Error while importing products through csv in magento 2

Tags: product, import, csv, url-key

I am trying to update my product price through csv.
When I run this import, I am getting this error:

-> The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
https://prnt.sc/te05st

I checked the url, they are the same but They do belong to different store. What can be the issue with this? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the URL of the existing product temporarily and import.

Once imported successfully, change the URL as it was previously.

Thank you.